# Other blockchain interaction on Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are considering the use of Hyperledger but not sure which "version" to use. We believe Fabric may be the best option given our goals. That being said, can someone tell me the following:

1. Does Fabric have out-of-the-box functionality to interact with other blockchains besides Ethereum?
2. If the answer is "no" to question #1, what would it require to build a custom solution that would allow interaction between Fabric and a public blockchain?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fabric 2.2 is the current LTS version of fabric, you could also consider 2.4 but be aware you will need to keep updating to newer 2.x releases to ensure you get the latest fixes until the next LTS version is released

Comment: I don't feel like this answered my question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is a comment about the first part of your question around which fabric version to use which was why it was only a comment, it doesn't provide an answer to the rest of your question. Maybe hyperledger firefly can can help with integrating with other blockchains. Not looked at it myself

Answer (score 0):

To interact with Ethereum you can use Hyperledger Besu which is an Ethereum Client: https://www.hyperledger.org/use/besu

To have interoperability across blockchains, like Fabric & Ethereum, you can use Hyperledger Cactus https://www.hyperledger.org/use/cactus